# Does mipmapping work with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT?

Tags: opengl, textures, depth, mipmaps

I'm trying to use mipmapping to get a downsampled version of a texture of type GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT. I enable mipmaps similar to this:

```
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

And use it in the shader like this:

```
texture2D(reference_view, coord, 5.0).bgr;
```

With 5.0 being the mipmap level I want to access.

This works fine for rgba textures, however I can't seem to get it work with the depth component texture. Is it even supported in opengl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it after all! Was some problem with the order of binding textures.

So the answer is: YES!

Answer (score -1):

No, OpenGL does not support mipmapping of GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT. But that shouldn't be the real problem.

It is a good idea to reconsider the reason you want to mipmap GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT. In practice, this shouldn't ever be a good idea. In situations where linear interpolation of depth values is required, a better way to achieve this is through a fragment shader.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I'm doing something similar to variance shadow mapping, and there it would be really handy.

Comment: I couldn't find the OpenGL specs anywhere, by the way... how do you know its not supported? Where did you get that information from?